# How to install a .deb file in Ubuntu-Touch?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch, deb

How can I install a .deb file in Ubuntu-Touch?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While technically you can download a .deb and install it, it's probably not a good idea in many instances.

You need to make the phone read-write (it ships read-only by default) which is not a good idea for most non-developers because the archive used for the phone isn't the full archive, so you may not even find the deb you want. We don't test `apt-get` installed scenarios on the phone and if you use `apt-get upgrade`, you may install packages which haven't yet been fully tested as part of image based updates.

That said, you can make the phone read-write:-

```
adb shell
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

You can then install a deb using usual tools:-

```
sudo dpkg -i PackageName.deb
```

However, you can break the phone and may need to re-flash from scratch if it breaks.

Comment: great helpful with this note: "We don't test apt-get installed scenarios on the phone and if you use "apt-get upgrade", you may install packages which haven't yet been fully tested as part of image based updates."

Comment: There is also a problem, that the system partition is to smal. Trying to install one package using apt results in out of memory error. So you also have to first reparttion the phone.