# What is Canonical's solution/strategy for Remote Desktop in Ubuntu?

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, mir, wayland, x2go

Ever since breaking solutions like xrdp with Unity's hardware acceleration, I've been wondering what Canonical would do to replace it or what their official recommendation would be.

Is this no longer a priority for Canonical/Ubuntu?
Is the recommendation to...

- Install a second / 3rd party desktop environment that works with x2go, etc?
- Use some other 3rd party remote desktop solution?
- "Figure it out" as an OSS community?

Would very much appreciate citing any official source or someone who is involved in the work that goes into Ubuntu/Mir/whatever-replaces-x11, etc. :)

Also I recognize this answer may change and get updated as Mir development continues...

Other people/places where this has been asked but I didn't find an answer:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241544

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/mir-devel/2015-March/001080.html

Probably relevant since Mir is used for mobile:
[Remote desktop/remote display viewer for Ubuntu Touch devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766269/remote-desktop-remote-display-viewer-for-ubuntu-touch-devices)

EDIT: To be clear I am not asking for "the best" - I am asking about Canonicals recommendation or their future plans for how remote desktop should work. "No plan" is also a valid answer.

Comment: It is xrdp's fault that they don't support a common, performance-boosting feature - hardware/3D acceleration.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I suppose it could be argued that it's Canonical's fault for making HW/3D accel mandatory. Who cares who is to "blame"? I want to know, when using Ubuntu, what's the prescribed approach to remote desktop? Also, why did I get a downvote?

Comment: Preferred - there is no official way, but if you are okay with some proprietary software, TeamViewer is fast and excellent.

Comment: Also, I don't know *exactly* why you got a downvote (since it wasn't me) but probably because any "What is the best *x* for *y* in Ubuntu" is opinion-based - can't be actually answered, matters on personal preference.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Raju thanks for your response. I agree with your point. I might not've been clear enough... I don't want the "best" I want the "official". Ubuntu used to ship with a " remote desktop" shortcut/settings. Does canonical have a recommendation? Maybe no... I just want to know if/what. :)

Comment: FWIW: you can use xpra with software 3D accel, or with hardware acceleration via virtualgl. (just not on all releases of Ubuntu, as some break Xdummy usage - and also stay away from the xpra packages in the Ubuntu repos..)